# MySQL - Make columns out of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have a table of tree diameters like this:

```
TreeID  Diameter
----------------
1       3
1       2
1       3
2       2
2       2
2       1
1       3
```

I would like to get up to six diameters for each tree in descending order like this:

```
TreeID  Diameter 1  Diameter 2  Diameter 3  Diameter 4  Diameter 5  Diameter 6
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       3           3           3           2
2       2           2           1
```

I have a query to get Diameters 1 through 6:

```
(SELECT Diameter FROM TreeDiameters ORDER BY Diameter DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS Diameter1
```

but I need to put in a WHERE clause so that the TreeID in this subselect matches the TreeID in the main SELECT. What is that WHERE clause?

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Strawberry The end goal is to generate a csv report that can be downloaded by whomever is querying the database via the website front end I've got. This is a small part of a bigger report query.

Comment: 'website front end'? I'd use that for the formatting!

Comment: @Strawberry Okay, so do some subqueries like select the top 6 diameters and finagle it that way?

Comment: No subqueries, just a join...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(measurement_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,TreeID  INT NOT NULL
,Diameter INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (treeid,diameter) VALUES
(1      , 3),
(1      , 2),
(1      , 3),
(2      , 2),
(2      , 2),
(2      , 1),
(1      , 3);

SELECT x.*
     , COUNT(*) rank
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.treeid = x.treeid
   AND 
     ( y.diameter > x.diameter
       OR (y.diameter = x.diameter AND y.measurement_id <= x.measurement_id )
     )
  GROUP 
     BY x.treeid, x.diameter, x.measurement_id
-- HAVING rank < something
  ORDER BY treeid,rank;

  +----------------+--------+----------+------+
  | measurement_id | TreeID | Diameter | rank |
  +----------------+--------+----------+------+
  |              1 |      1 |        3 |    1 |
  |              3 |      1 |        3 |    2 |
  |              7 |      1 |        3 |    3 |
  |              2 |      1 |        2 |    4 |
  |              4 |      2 |        2 |    1 |
  |              5 |      2 |        2 |    2 |
  |              6 |      2 |        1 |    3 |
  +----------------+--------+----------+------+
```

Comment: This gets me closest to what I want and I think I can take it from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is if you put the diameters in a single column, separated by a delimiter.  Then you can use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT TreeId, substring_index(group_concat(Diameter order by Diameter desc), ',', 6)
FROM TreeDiameters
GROUP BY TreeId
ORDER BY Diameter DESC;
```

Six actual columns requires a bit more work.